# Can a particular component(step) in a kubeflow pipeline be scaled(autosclaed) horizontally?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, pipeline, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

All this while I was using lightweight python function as a component in kubeflow pipeline but recently I switched to use docker container as a component in kubeflow pipeline which goes something like this...

```
    produce: str = 'hello'
):
    return dsl.ContainerOp(
        name = 'Say hi', 
        image = 'docker.io/playground/comp1:latest', 
        command = ['python', 'msg.py'],
        arguments=[
            '--msg', send_msg
        ],
        file_outputs={
            'output': '/output.txt',
        }
    )
```

Do i need to to some changes in the above code? do i need to autoscale docker container? if so how will the *dsl.ContainerOp* know which instance of docker container it should hit?

I did a lot of searching and also explored kfp package to see if that helps but to my luck i could not even find a closer solution to it. 
First of all is it possible? Am i in the right direction?
Can someone please help me in my R&D?

Answer (score 3):

> I was using lightweight python function as a component in kubeflow pipeline but recently I switched to use docker container as a component

1. Lightweight components **are** proper container components. You can export them to `component.yaml` files and share them: `create_component_from_func(my_func, output_component_file='component.yaml')` or (same) `func_to_container_op(my_func, output_component_file='component.yaml')`
2. `ContainerOp`s are **not** components. They're half-compiled task-like objects. We advice our users not to create them directly, but create real reusable components instead.

`component.yaml`

```
name: 'Say hi'
inputs:
- {name: Message}
outputs:
- {name: Output}
implementation:
  container:
    image: 'docker.io/playground/comp1:latest'
    command: ['python', 'msg.py']
    args: [
      '--msg', {inputValue: Message},
      '--output', {outputPath: Output},
    ]
```

Then load it using `load_component_from_file` or `load_component_from_url` or `load_component_from_text` and use it in multiple pipelines.
Reusable components automatically produce `ContainerOp`s when you instantiate them.

3. Execution-wise there is no difference between lightweight components, components loaded from component.yaml and manually created ContainerOp instances.

> Do i need to to some changes in the above code? do i need to autoscale docker container?

Probably not. Kubernetes' autoscaling is an opt-in feature that starts more nodes when they load is high. SO it only kicks in when you run many heavy tasks in parallel. If you just run a single task, there is nothing to scale.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no issue with the code and you are on the right track. As per the GCP documentation [click here](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/reasons/), you can take advantage of GKE autoscaling to scale up your workload horizontally. That being said you can define a pod in a deployment manifest. Please note that, the pod will contain the kubeflow component like a container. For detailed information, please follow the link [here](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/pipelines/preemptible/) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253586/kubeflow-pipeline-doesnt-create-any-pod-unknown-status). I hope this helps you to solve the issue.